# php echo within javascript possible?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to add a php echo within javascript (for translation reasons). But it seems as though I cannot echo from javascript?

This is the initial code:

```
else if(o.thumbplacement=='bottom'){$outer.append('<div style="padding-top:4px; text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color: #999; "><img src="images/magnify.png" alt="enlarge" />  Click and move to zoom</div><ul class="thumbs">'+cont+'</ul>');}
```

This is how I edited it:

```
else if(o.thumbplacement=='bottom'){$outer.append('<div style="padding-top:4px; text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color: #999; "><img src="images/magnify.png" alt="enlarge" />  <?php echo TEXT_CLICK_TO_ENLARGE; ?></div><ul class="thumbs">'+cont+'</ul>');}
```

I also tried just

`<?php echo "test"; ?>` which returns nothing as well.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have to encode in json format : echo json_encode("test");

Comment: Yes, this is possible. make sure you're using a .php file and not a .js file, or you setup your webserver to send .js files to php (probably a bad idea). Though there's likely a MUCH better way of handling translations

Comment: You can generate JavaScript from PHP. Don't look at the PHP and say that the JavaScript doesn't work. Look at the JavaScript you get when you run the PHP, then figure out why it doesn't work, then figure out how to fix it, then figure out to make PHP output the fixed JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a more detailled answer : You can generate Javascript from PHP, so obviously you can generate a string in PHP like this (in a PHP file) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mytext = <?php echo json_encode("Hello World!"); ?>
</script>
```

Then you can access the `mytext` variable in your javascript code.

BUT you cannot call PHP in your JS file, because PHP run on server side, and Javascript (well in your case) on client side.

Anyway, I think it is a bad idea to translate stuff like this... Either you directly do the translatation in your HTML code using PHP, or you import a "database" file containing the translation for the current language. There are tons of javascript translation libraries (i18n).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late reply. This one helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

It's **positively impossible**.

By the time JS start execution, PHP is died already long time ago.

One can easily *generate* any JS out of PHP though, exactly the same way they generate HTML and any other output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to your document with Javascript you need to use

```
 document.write("Hello World!");
```

This will output to the DOM. As other answers suggest PHP has completed when your Javascript is run so you can't do what you want.

I think my answer is what you are trying to achieve.

document.write is the kinda like the echo equivalent in JS.

If you need bits from your DB at this late stage you need to AJAX them and them add them to the document.